# Stop Xorg without changing to its TTY

Tags: xorg, tty, x

If I change TTY to `2`, then run `startx`, then change to TTY `1` and stop Xorg (by killing Xorg or the process I started with `startx`), TTY changes to `2`. Can I stop Xorg without switching, i.e. stay on the same TTY?

Comment: Killing X requires X to become active, which requires the tty X is on to become active. Of course you can change back ("stay on the same TTY"), if you remember which TTY you were on somewhere...

Comment: @dirkt Right, but if I do `service lightdm start`, then return to TTY 1 and do `service lightdm stop`, I stay on TTY 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start Xorg with the -novtswitch option.

From [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-start-x-without-changing-to-its-vt-automatically-novtswitch-seem-not-to-work-535756/).